# if i click button load same page again

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, click

when i click button, always load same page in my mobile. it's only happen mobile phone. desktop and tablet, it's work grate. please help.

```
<a href="#a2"  class="nav-btn">Next</a><a class="rest nav-btn">Reset</a>
```

```js
$('a[href*=#a2]').click(function(e){
    var link = "#b11"
    gotoSection(link);
    //console.log(link);
});

function gotoSection(temp){
    var location = temp.split("#");
    $('div').find('h1').each(function( index ) {
      if($(this).data('url')==location[1]){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(parent).offset().top-70}, 1000);
      } 
    });
}
```

this is the code .. and please refer below link and open using phone. click skip button or next green button.
[click this url](http://pixellersthemes.com/test_db/male/index.html)

thank you.